# grep -f failing on a file edited in Windows

Tags: grep, windows, patterns

I just want to share a problem I had this morning using grep -f to obtain the patterns to match from a text file.

**Symptom**

```
$ echo 'sandbox/test/script.py' | grep -G '^sandbox/'
sandbox/test/script.py
```

Using -f option fails:

```
$ echo 'sandbox/test/script.py' | grep -G -f patterns.txt
$ cat patterns.txt
^sandbox/
```

I didn't understand why grep was failing until I inspected the text file:

```
$ file patterns.txt
/home/miguel/patterns.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

This file was being used by different colleagues on different Operating Systems, and someone saved it using the Windows line terminators.

Comment: dos2unix will fix it.

Comment: Yes, check the solution below.

Comment: `-f` means *fixed* patterns, no regexps (and no anchors either).

Comment: That is why I used the -G flag, which interprets a pattern (obtained from the text file) as a basic regular expression. The -f is for obtaining the patterns from a text file, one per line.

Comment: @vonbrand, I think you have `-f` and `-F` mixed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Using dos2unix solved the problem.

```
$ dos2unix patterns.txt
dos2unix: converting file /home/miguel/patterns.txt to Unix format ...
$ file patterns.txt
/home/miguel/patterns.txt: ASCII text
```

And now grep -f works again.

```
$ echo 'sandbox/test/script.py' | grep -G -f patterns.txt
sandbox/test/script.py
```